# Convex Polygon Inscribed in a Circle

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider a convex polygon with $n$ sides inscribed in a circle. We denote $P$ its perimeter and $e^{ia_1},\ldots, e^{ia_n}$ its vertices with $0<a_1<a_2<\ldots<2\pi$.

Show that
[this polygon perimeter equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVWm.png)
holds.

I understand how to do this for a regular polygon (drawing a line from the center of the circle to each vertex and then calculating the circumference from the side length of each triangle), but how would you do this with a convex polygon?

Comment: Should $a_{n-1} - a_n$ be $a_{k-1} - a_k$ in the perimeter equation?

Comment: The approach you describe for regular polygons still works.